# Sending data between users in the form of nsstrings - http post method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling quite a bit with this concept of setting up the server to communicate with the iOS app as I'm quite a new at programming (I know the basics about Objective-C, but not very much about servers), but what I was hoping to do is submit the data I need in the form of a NSString to the server, then sending it to another user of the same app on another iPhone, like a message. I was wondering if this is possible, communicating with other iPhone users through the same app remotely, without using bluetooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really broad question so please forgive the broad response.

Are you limited by distance, i.e. will they be in the same room or far away from each other.  If they would be close by then maybe the multipeer connectivity framework is an option.  I suspect from the no bluetooth part that this isn't the case.

Given that your new to using a remote server for an app my guess is that you don't have the skills or desire to maintain one yourself.  In this case there are are lots of services called Baas (backend as a service), Parse is one such provider but there are many others out there.  With that said you might want to check out firebase https://www.firebase.com/, they are more chatty and do more real time communication (I bring this up because you mentioned sending a message to another app).  In general all of them should have an easy to use SDK which makes working with their service fairly easy.

Comment: I apologize for the broadness of my question, I'm very unfamiliar with the concept of HTTP Post method, as you can probably tell. Yes, it probably will be as well to choose a pre-existing service to complete the duties that I am looking for, however, perhaps, my question is loosely based on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444216/need-a-basic-server-backend-for-ios-app in which the user wants to complete similar duties but only wants to relay the string back to their own app. Therefore I believed it would be a similar process, but more complicated.

Comment: Just explored your links, and I have to say firebase works quite well for what I am planning on doing. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped.  If it answers your question please accept the answer.