# what are the motifs for storing database knowledge on the iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

Wanting to make an app for the iphone/iOS, I'm wondering how to handle *user logins* and *loading data* ... should I (absolutely) have a living web back-end or are there alternatives?

(for data accessed from many distinct devices)

also found this useful question:
[Need a basic server backend for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444216/need-a-basic-server-backend-for-ios-app)

Comment: If the data only has to stay on the device the you can use Core Data. If you need data to be accessible from multiple devices then you need some sort of server

Comment: You should check out Parse.com for user logins.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your comment; the data would be accessible from many devices (being a collaborative database of stuff).

Comment: So you need some sort of server.  As suggest, Parse.com may be an option worth looking at