# Where to place(what technology to choice) data source to fetch updates from my iOS application?

Tags: ios, database, https

My iOS application is deployed with a predefined set of texts.
I want to be able to provide new texts to the users as I write them, so they will have an opportunity to access latest data.
I need to upload texts(no processing on the backend side is required) and app will check for updates fetching list of available text from the given URL, and downloading new texts.

Options I consider:

1. Shared hosting(like drop box, google drive etc)
2. Renting a host server

Of course being a single developer I want costs for this as low as possible

This is related question(I decided to ask another question, as latest answer from this is dated 2011, and I think a lot might have changed since that time)
[Need a basic server backend for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444216/need-a-basic-server-backend-for-ios-app)

Could you,please, give me advices on the options I consider as I this can be done easier it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) provides a lot of useful functionality for your apps and it is free if you don't use lots of resources.
You can use Firebase Database for store your texts.
[Here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) is the pricing.

With this simple method you can keep your texts update:

```
refHandle = postRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out. And that do you think about other options?

Comment: @spin_eight I think this is the best solution. Other options are: Parse OpenSource (it was a free backend that closed last year), a normal SQL database (you create a PHP file and access it from your app)

Comment: ok, I shall try it and let you know about my results, but this will take some time. Also, can you tell me If in future I want to change(migrate my database) from one source(firebase) to another how can I do that, is there something like patch for this purpose?

Comment: You can export your database as json file

Comment: I have studied Firebase basic functionality, that is what I need, great! Thank you very much!